# Modules of Veins documentation

Tags: module, documentation, veins, simulte

Does anyone know how to use the make proxy command from the command line in order to see the documentations of the modules? I have installed Instant Veins 5.0 i2 with SimuLTE. It doesn't work generating from the IDE of OMNeT++, it returns an error and the cars simulation can't run, so i need to re-install the whole instant-veins-5.0-i2-simulte.ova file from scratch.

Comment: Your question has me confused. Are you asking how to use the Linux command line to create a SOCKS proxy? How to generate C++ documentation in Instant Veins 5.0? How to run a simulation?

Comment: I want to read the documentation of Veins_LTE. As it is recommended in veins.car2x.org/documentation/modules  you can do this by The IDE. But when I try, it's not working. So, the other option is from command line by running make doxy... But how? in which path?

Answer (score 0):

For "Veins LTE 1.3", module documentation can be generated by opening a terminal, changing to the `veins/` directory (the one that contains `sumo-launchd.py`), and running `make doxy`. Module documentation is then available in `doc/doxy/index.html`.

Note, however, that Veins LTE has not been in active development for quite some time and integrating much more recent versions of SimuLTE and Veins is now possible via Veins_INET. For more details, see https://veins.car2x.org/documentation/modules/#lte